# Content doesn't fit in one slide

Tags: beamer, height

I have a paragraph which I want to put in one slide, but it doesn't fit and some content can't be seen. I am using the Warsaw theme as follows.

I tried increasing the height of the slide using the following code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[height=10in,a5paper,hmargin={3cm,0.8in}]{geometry} 

\title[\insertframenumber/
\inserttotalframenumber]{Database}
\author{Mark dain \\ \scriptsize{(Reg.No 12345)} }
\institute{Dept. of Information \& Communication Technology}
\date{October 21,2012}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\begin{itemize}
\item Introduction
\item Algorithm for reducing finite automata
\item Reliability models
\item Reduction steps
\item References
\item Conclusion
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Title}
text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However it still doesn't increase.

Comment: It's no use increasing the height of the slides; did you try putting `\small` or `\footnotesize` just after `\begin{frame}`?

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense to mess with beamer's page sizes using geometry rather than its inbuilt methods, if I get an error from the example as posted but it works fine if I comment out the `\usepackage`. Unrelated you are missing a `%` after `\insertframenumber/` (or put a space before the `/` to match the space after it). Also why do a table of contents "by hand" in latex, normally you just use `\tableofcontents`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have several possibilities here:

1. Use `\setbeamersize` to reduce the left and right margins (default =`1cm`); notice that this will have a global effect (all frames will suffer the change):

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}
   \usepackage{lmodern}
   \setbeamercovered{transparent}
   \usetheme{Warsaw}

   \title[\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber]{Database}
   \author{Mark dain \\ \scriptsize{(Reg.No 12345)} }
   \institute{Dept. of Information \& Communication Technology}
   \date{October 21,2012}

   \setbeamersize{text margin left=0.5cm,text margin right=0.5cm}

   \begin{document}

   \frame{\titlepage}

   \begin{frame}
   \frametitle{Table of Contents}
   \tableofcontents
   \end{frame}

   \section{Introduction}
   \begin{frame}{Title}
   text
   \end{frame}
   \section{Algorithm for reducing finite automata}
   \begin{frame}{Title}
   text
   \end{frame}
   \section{Reliability models}
   \begin{frame}{Title}
   text
   \end{frame}
   \section{Reduction steps}
   \begin{frame}{Title}
   text
   \end{frame}

   \end{document}
   ```
2. Use `\footnotesize` (or other font switch) to reduce the font size in the given frame:

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}
   \usepackage{lmodern}
   \setbeamercovered{transparent}
   \usetheme{Warsaw}
   \usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

   \title[\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber]{Database}
   \author{Mark dain \\ \scriptsize{(Reg.No 12345)} }
   \institute{Dept. of Information \& Communication Technology}
   \date{October 21,2012}

   \begin{document}

   \frame{\titlepage}

   \begin{frame}
   \frametitle{Table of Contents}
   \tableofcontents
   \end{frame}

   \section{Introduction}
   \begin{frame}{Title}
   \footnotesize
   \lipsum[2]\lipsum[3]
   \end{frame}
   \section{Algorithm for reducing finite automata}
   \begin{frame}{Title}
   text
   \end{frame}
   \section{Reliability models}
   \begin{frame}{Title}
   text
   \end{frame}
   \section{Reduction steps}
   \begin{frame}{Title}
   text
   \end{frame}

   \end{document}
   ```
3. Use the `shrink` option for the frame:

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}
   \usepackage{lmodern}
   \setbeamercovered{transparent}
   \usetheme{Warsaw}
   \usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

   \title[\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber]{Database}
   \author{Mark dain \\ \scriptsize{(Reg.No 12345)} }
   \institute{Dept. of Information \& Communication Technology}
   \date{October 21,2012}

   \begin{document}

   \frame{\titlepage}

   \begin{frame}
   \frametitle{Table of Contents}
   \tableofcontents
   \end{frame}

   \section{Introduction}
   \begin{frame}[shrink=20]{Title}
   \lipsum[2]\lipsum[3]
   \end{frame}
   \section{Algorithm for reducing finite automata}
   \begin{frame}{Title}
   text
   \end{frame}
   \section{Reliability models}
   \begin{frame}{Title}
   text
   \end{frame}
   \section{Reduction steps}
   \begin{frame}{Title}
   text
   \end{frame}

   \end{document}
   ```

Notice that I replaced the manually generated table of contents by the automatically generated one using `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. i used \setbeamersize and it worked :)

Comment: shrink (option 3 above) works very well. Its just that the number in the shrink has to be entered manually. It would be good if [shrink=*] autoresized the frame contents!

Comment: putting just [shrink] would "autofit" the content onto the slide.

Comment: For text "shrink" is not suitable because it also makes the lines shorter. Better use method (2): put "\small" or some other size switcher after \begin{frame}.

Comment: In my experience shrink makes the lines shorter when the amount to shrink by is not enough. For instance, ``shrink=10`` reduces the line width, but ``shrink=20`` might be just right. You need to tweak the value of shrink before it looks right. If the lines are short, you probably will find a message in the log file to inform you that beamer shrunk by some other value instead.

Comment: It looks to me like `shrink` also messes up the links: the linked text and the space where one is supposed to click (to follow the link) do not coincide anymore.